# Does the Thomson scattering from a free (moving) electron differ from that of a bound (hence stationary) electron?

Tags: photons, scattering-cross-section, x-rays

By definition, Thomson scattering refers to the elastic scattering in electrons. however, X-ray scientists prefer to use the term XRTS (X-Ray Thomson Scattering) to describe a board range of processes that involves energy shift of photons. Here we consider an Xray laser that shoots on electrons.

As a simplified model, the Thomson scattering from one single bound electron in an atom (hence stationary) is elastic. If the laser is linearly polarised, the cross-section of this process is
$$\frac{{\rm d}\sigma}{{\rm d}\Omega}=r_{\rm e}^2({\rm Sin}[\theta])^2.$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between the polarisation direction and the detection.

This predicts an angular preference of scattered photons: more photons will be scattered at the equator, and fewer will be scattered to the polar. (The z-direction is assumed to be the polarization direction).

Now I'm considering an electron that is moving - with relatively high speed, say $v=\frac{1}{10}c$. My question is, will the direction that the electron travels affect the angular distribution and the cross-section?

The first thing that jumped to my mind is how this would be affected be frame transformation - a rather direct approach is to transform to a frame where the electron is stationary, and I obtain the frequency of the laser via Doppler shift, and the Lorentz transformation of EM field defines a new polarization direction, so we need to calculate a new $\theta'$ in that frame. This yields a new angular distribution of scattered photons in the moving frame, hence if I transform back to the lab frame I acquired the cross-section which depends on the electron motion and the detection angle.

As this seems to be a rather trivial (but complicated) calculation, it must be on some paper a century ago. Is there any reference?